# How to adjust this control flow of the 3 threads?

Tags: java, executorservice

```
// Task 1 -- the main thread
        SimilarityResponse w2vResponse = questionClassifier.compute(questionInfo);

        // Task 2
        String sku = questionInfo.getSku();
        String question = questionInfo.getQuestion();
        Callable<ResponseList> dssmTask = () -> this.dssmCompute(sku, question);
        Future<ResponseList> dssmService = executorService.submit(dssmTask);
        ResponseList dssmResponse;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("start dssm ... {} ", question);
            dssmResponse = dssmService.get(Parameters.getParserTimeLimit(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            LOGGER.info("dssmResponse ... {} ", dssmResponse);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("ExecutionException | InterruptedException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException te) {
            dssmService.cancel(true);
            LOGGER.warn("DSSM time out for {} {}", sku, question);
        }

        // Task 3
        Callable<ResponseList> stsTask = () -> this.stsCompute(sku, question);
        Future<ResponseList> stsService = executorService.submit(stsTask);
        ResponseList stsResponse;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("start sts ... {} ", question);
            stsResponse = stsService.get(Parameters.getParserTimeLimit(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            LOGGER.info("stsResponse ... {} ", stsResponse);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("ExecutionException | InterruptedException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TimeoutException te) {
            stsService.cancel(true);
            LOGGER.warn("STS time out for {} {}", sku, question);
        }

        // Last step == do something for above
        SimilarityResponse ensemble = new SimilarityResponse();
        return ensemble;
```

Before executing the last step, how can I make sure the Task 1-3 are already completed? The current code seems it finishes Task 1 first and then directly returns.

Comment: What about `CompletableFuture.allOf(task1, task2, task3).thenApply(lastTask)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use CountDownLatch. Create instance of it in your main thread and pass this instance to your tasks (Callables). Then when task is finished call latch.countDown(). In the last step of your code call latch.await() to wait for each task to finish. It would look something like this (if your callables were created as lambdas):

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    service.submit( () -> {
        // do something
        latch.countDown();
    });
}

// in the end wait for tasks to finish
latch.await();
```